# AWS API Gateway HTTP Proxy for HTTPS connections

Tags: aws-api-gateway, http-proxy

I cannot for the life of me get the AWS API Gateway HTTP Proxy to work, i.e. redirect `http://<my-domain>.com` to `https://<my-domain>.com`. Here is how I set it up:
[image: resource setup]
[image: any method]

Using the `Test` functionality on the `ANY` method inside the resource works. But if I simply do `curl http://<my-domain>.com` or run `http://<my-domain>.com` in Chrome, it fails to connect; `https://<my-website>.com` works just fine. I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out what I'm missing here; it seems like it should just redirect `http://<my-domain>.com` to `https://<my-domain>.com`, but it doesn't (even on different devices).

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out that API Gateway's HTTP Proxy allows HTTPS traffic to go to an HTTP endpoint, but not the reverse. In fact, API Gateway won't even establish a connection on port 80; from the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/):

> Q: Can I create HTTPS endpoints?
>
> Yes, all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS
> endpoints only. Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP)
> endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway doesn't support unencrypted HTTP traffic. Here are the possible options you can do to secure your website:

- If you have access to the server that hosts the website, install an SSL certificate to the webserver.
- If the website is hosted on EC2, you can set up a load balancer and let it do the SSL termination.

Comment: I think you mean _unsecured_... but yes